# detect circles from the image using Hough Circle transform

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I am trying to detect circles from the following image using Hough Circles function of OpenCV

[image]

My code (OpenCV with Python)

```
myImage = cv2.imread("C:\\sample.jpg") 
img = cv2.resize(myImage,(640,480))        
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10, param1=50,param2=35,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(myImage,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(myImage,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
cv2.imshow('detected circles',myImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But due to some reason, I am not able to get the correct outputs. I am getting the following output

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks it's working now. By setting the `param2` high I am able to detect 2 circles. I was displaying them wrongly and now everything is fine

Comment: are those circles? look like ellipses to me

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have given the coordinates wrong.

```
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(myImage,(i[1],i[0]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(myImage,(i[1],i[0]),2,(0,0,255),3)
```

Change that to

```
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(myImage,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(myImage,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
```

Comment: just did that but still output is not correct ..see my update

Comment: did you change both the cordinates?

Comment: yeap plz see new picture

Comment: Please post the full code. A total of 6 centers are being detected while there are only 4 objects in the image and only one circle. Something is wrong with the code. Try changing the param1 and param2 to smaller and higher values

Comment: @user1388142 Try increasing the param2 to a large value say 50 or 75 and see what the output is..

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing is that max radius is set at 0...

i.e. your range is 0 < radius < 0.

Unless I'm mistaken (?) that's a wee bit restrictive yeah?

Comment: afaik 0 means no restriction, so ALL sizes should be considered by the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the original image `cv2.imshow('detected circles',myImage)` but the circles are computed over the gray reescales image. Change

```
cv2.imshow('detected circles',myImage)
```

for

```
cv2.imshow('detected circles',img)
```

and you are done.